# how rabbitmq delay message exchange do disaster recovery?

Tags: plugins, rabbitmq, recovery

I am using the delay message exchange plugin in rabbitmq,
I know that this plugin store message in mnesia in disk.

currently, I only run one node for rabbitmq server, if the disk fail,
all the delay message will missed.

I want to know how to do disaster recovery for it.